# Is a self exciting high output alternator a bad idea?

Tags: honda, alternator, accord, accessories

My vehicle ('12 Accord LX 2.4l) has electronics that are constantly running: Compustar Drone & Compustar EZ-GO

It seems as though, the ELD prevent the battery from charging, and simply maintains the voltage but because it never charges to replace what it lost it slowly drains the battery over the course of few months down to 12v.

I've read ways to bypass the ELD but I believe this will only bring the charge up to a constant 14.4v.

I need to purchase a HO alternator anyways for my amplifiers and was told I could just order a "self-exciting" alternator that'll always charge at 14.8v - Would this be bad for my battery for the voltage to constantly be at 14.8?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!